# HTML text gets smaller on vertically held Android device

Tags: android, html, css, fonts

I am working on a type of social network - unfortunately I cannot show anybody the website as somebody might steal the idea. Apologies for not trusting my comrades at Stack Overflow!

I have successfully been able to fix text getting bigger on Android browsers, but now a title gets smaller when the device is held vertically.

HTML:

```
<div class="title">
    Lorem ipsum - that is all I remember
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content .title {
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #1d2021;

    padding: 0 0 45px 0;

    text-align: center;
}
```

Thankyou comrades,
Foru

Answer (score 1):

for better practice, use `h1` tag instead of a `div`

EDIT:

You can still use media queries:

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait){
    // css when held vertically 
}
```